How to determine whether the screen printing is M2W chip model?

I am currently trying to fix a board and I found this SOT23 component labeled M2W, but I can't find this IC model.

Using a multimeter to measure this chip, it is found that

the junction voltage between pin3 (positive) and pin1 and pin2 (negative) of this chip is 0.7 V,
there is a voltage of 0.2 V between pin1 and pin2, and
there is also a voltage of 0.2 V between pin2 and pin1.

Please help confirm the chip model or recommend a chip model with similar performance.

Please add a picture of the chip with readable markings and the surrounding area visible. I also don't understand the symbol in your schematic. You say the IC is SOT23, but in the schematic it has 4 connections and what looks like 6 pads.

In this picture, there are two chips

Your symbol doesn't follow conventions and is unreadable for anyone but you. Please take a picture of the IC and the board, it will be more helpful and it's actually required for identification questions to not get closed.

From the markings, it's possibly a NXP BFR31 JFET. I can't tell from your schematic if that makes sense function wise, but the markings of older Philips/NXP parts look very similar style wise.

(Source: nxp.com)

(Source: aliexpress.com)

But I have done experiments with bfr31, and the noise is very loud at the bottom of the low frequency band, should it be another model?

From the PCB layout (and @nanash1's excellent sleuthing +1), it looks like there are two JFETs connected as back-to-back low leakage diodes, which I would guess might be protection for a multimeter circuit or something of that ilk.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Pretty much any similar JFET should work okay in this application.

But I have done experiments with bfr31, and the noise is very loud at the bottom of the low frequency band, should it be another model?
When measuring with a multimeter, I test the chip by removing it from the circuit board
